# How to backup only comments in my site

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

In my website many comments have been added, while I worked on improvements at my localhost. Now I want to transfer the database from my system to the online website.

**I want to retain the comments added online. How can I do it?**

Comment: Are the comments in the form of a blog or forum?  Are they stored in a database such as MySQL?  If so, do you have access to a tool such as PHPMyAdmin for the database?

Comment: No they are the node type-page comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stage this to make sure it works properly, but install [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) and create a profile that only backs up the `comments` table.  Run the backup manually on the live host, and restore it on the devel host.

The complication would be any other modules that implement [hook_comment](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_comment/6) and store things elsewhere.

Comment: Can't I just take backup & restore comments table using phpmyadmin? How to avoid any such complication? Because in the long run I'll not be able to remember who is catching hook_comment etc, I wanna avoid such "tricks".

Comment: You have the same problem with any tool.  Depending on what modules you are using, there may be a table in addition to comments that has info in it.  You can use module_implements() to see what is calling the comments hooks.  Personally, I use Backup and Migrate for scheduled safety backups via cron, and quick "just in case" backups when testing new code.  Since everything is done via Drupal admin or drush, it is very quick.  I use MySQL Administrator for full migrations and large scale backup/restores.  I really don't like phpmyadmin.  YMMV.

Comment: How can you call Backup & Migrate outside Drupal? That is from cron? I've heard that this module can give some problems. Can I fully rely on it?

Comment: B&M has drush hooks, so you can call it that way.  It also implements hook_cron(), so you can schedule it (eg, daily backups)  I have never had problems with it, but I also put my sites into maintenance mode when it runs.  I backup/restore frequently when developing custom import scripts and when doing direct db shenanigans from custom modules, and have never had it botch a site.

Comment: If you are comfortable doing database dumps in a particular way, do it that way. B&M is a Drupal-integrated way, and offers no special advantages for a task like this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the comments table in both databases are the same. Doing a mysql dump of the data, and then importing the dump would do this for you.

Comment: Are you saying that by backup & restore of comments table will do?

Comment: Yes, that should work. Make sure you make a full backup of both tables before you start just to be safe. But that should work.